# Only show tables in left hand column instead of databases in phpmyadmin

Tags: linux, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

I updated phpmyadmin today via the ubuntu updater.  I now have red exclamation marks next to all my databases.  Also, when I click into a database, the tables within that db don't appear in the left hand pane, the databases remain.  How can I change this?  I don't see a PMA database either, so I think this has gone.

EDIT:  I have noticed that I am able to click to the left of the db name to get the tables within that db to drop down like a tree structure. I want it like it was before though, with all the tables in that db to show.

Answer (score 1):

With the version 4.4 of phpMyAdmin (soon to be released I think), it will be possible to revert back to old-style navigation panel with a database selector and only current databases' tables being displayed. For switching this behavior, set configuration option $cfg['ShowDatabasesNavigationAsTree'] to 'false'.